# Accessing 'Modified By' field in a reusable workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I'm creating a reusable workflow in SharePoint designer 2010. I've created a custom content type with all the necessary fields that I'll be used in the workflow. But I'm not able to get the Modified By field (Editor) inside the workflow.

```
<FieldRef ID="{d31655d1-1d5b-4511-95a1-7a09e9b75bf2}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Name="Editor" DisplayName="Last Updated By"  FromBaseType="TRUE" Required="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node="" />
```

I really doubt whether the ID is matching with the inbuilt editor field. How can I cross-verify this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but do you really need to include it explicitly? Editor is part of base content type : Item, and down the hierarchy all other content types should be inheriting it without the need to explicitly include it.

Regards,
Nitin Rastogi

Comment: Thought the same. But I dint get it in the list of columns inside the workflow.